# simulate alt+enter to create newline within cell CSV output from PHP to Excel

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm generating a CSV file using PHP and opening it in Excel.  Adding "\n" at the end of each record creates a new line and works perfectly, however I need to figure out a way to create a newline within a cell itself.  The same functionality that alt+enter achieves when entering data manually into Excel.  Does anyone have any insight as to how this can be performed?  I have tried "\n\r", "\n", chr(10), none of which seem to work, just keep getting a complete new line instead of newline within the same cell.

What I want to achieve is a header that looks like this...
This is all in one row in Excel..

### CELL

Start Date
End Date

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you creating the csv file?
If you're doing it correctly and using `fputcsv`, having a line break within a cell wouldn't cause an issue.

[Documentation to fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried "\n\r", "\n",

Use `"\r\n"` :) Check [the wiki article about 'Newline'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

But note that you'll have to use double quotes. `"` otherwise PHP will not handle meta characters.